# Jpa namedquery with left join fetch

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, named-query

this is my namedquery:

> @NamedQuery(
>                   name = "User.findOneWithLists",
>                   query = "SELECT u FROM User u "
>                           + "LEFT JOIN FETCH u.aTemplates "
>                           + "LEFT JOIN FETCH u.bTemplates "
>                           + "LEFT JOIN FETCH u.bp "
>                           + "LEFT JOIN FETCH u.aCredentials "
>                           + "LEFT JOIN FETCH u.st WHERE (st.deleted = false) "
>                           + "LEFT JOIN FETCH u.bCredentials "
>                           + "LEFT JOIN FETCH u.cl "
>                           + "WHERE u.id= :id")

My problem is that I get an error when the application starting:

**org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: LEFT ....**

On the st side there is an annotation

```
@ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "st_user")
 private User user;
```

Any idea how can I handle this where clause?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check a SQL syntax, you can't use `left join` after `where` clause. If you are looking at the SQL generated form that named query you will see that joined tables in the query the `where` clause comes after joins and should specify equal condition that links those tables by the keys. The primary key of the main table on the left and the foreign key of the joined table on the right. The joined table is specified by the property of your many-to-one association.

```
@NamedQuery(
    name = "findOneWithLists",
    query = "from Table t left join User u where u.id= :id"
)
```

Comment: ok but how can i do a left join with a where or something similar

Comment: It's not SQL. It's JPQL. JPQL doesn't use tables. It uses entities. The first sentence of the answer is correct, but the rest isn't.

Comment: @JBNizet that's right, JPQL, or HQL don't require the condition, but SQL generated uses them.

Comment: @user3296520 if you're using JPA 2.1, you can use the ON clause, as you would in SQL: `left join u.st st on st.deleted = false`. But you can't use an ON clause on a left join **fetch**. The "sts" of a user always contain *all* the sts of the user. You can't load a user and pretent it only has non-deleted sts.

Answer (score 0):

For join conditions Hibernate provides the `with` keyword, even before JPA 2.1.

The relevant part of your query thus would look like this:

```
SELECT u FROM User u  ... LEFT JOIN u.st WITH st.deleted = false
```

I'm not sure about `LEFT JOIN FETCH u.cl with u.id= :id` but if I remember correctly, that's not as easy and might have to be resolved with an adapted join and `u.ui = :id` in the where condition.

> LEFT JOIN **FETCH** u.st WITH st.deleted = false`

This is not supported, since you can't do a partial fetch.